# Homography from football (soccer) field lines

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am working on using video from a football (soccer) match and try to map the frames to a top view of the pitch using homography. I have started to get find all the white lines from the frames using both Hough lines as well as using the line segment detector, where the line segment detector seems to work slightly better. See my code and examples below:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.imread("frame-27.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
mask_green = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255, 255)) # green mask to select only the field
frame_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask_green)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_masked, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
# Hough line detection
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 20)
# Line segment detection
lines_lsd = lsd.detect(canny)[0]
```

This uses this input frame

[image]

and returns this image for the Hough lines

[image]

and this image for the line segment detection.

[image]

My question is twofold: (1) any ideas on how I can further refine the line detection (i.e. decrease false positives such as lines around players and outside of the field) and (2) a good way to use the detection lines to create a homography so I can map the frame to a higher overview of the field ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmFdA.png)). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have the line segments as individual objects, I would try filtering them according to their length, e.g. keep only the 10-20 or so longest line segments. At least from your example, that should filter out most of the false positives.

Comment: That seems to sort of work, when doing it that way I seem to miss quite some of the actual lines of the field. Using the line segment detector seems to work a bit better and also decreases the number of false positives a bit. Do you have any ideas on a good way to extract points which I can map to a top down view of the field?

Comment: Find intersections of lines that are near the endpoints of the lines.

Answer (score 9):

## Pencils of lines

Cluster line segments in two pencils of lines using RANSAC. A pencil of lines is a set of lines that intersect at a common point. With homogeneous coordinates, the intersection point may potentially be at infinity (e.g. if all the lines are parallel).

You can find two random line segments, compute their intersection, and then consider all the lines that go somewhat close to that intersection point (within some threshold). Repeat this until you find the two pencils with the greatest amount of line segments. We can then assume that these pencils correspond to the vanishing points.

[image: line segments]

Here, the blue and red segments correspond to two pencils of lines. The green segments are outliers. As you can see the RANSAC algorithm is extremely good at rejecting outliers.

## Rectifying

I am not aware of built-in OpenCV rectification for line segments specifically; the existing functions are designed to work with point correspondences.

Run an optimization to recover the homography to deal with orientation. Generally the homography `H` is of the form `H = KRK^-1` where `K` is the intrinsic matrix and `R` is the rotation matrix.

For example, you can run a nonlinear least squares optimization on the manifold of the Lie group SO(3) to recover the `R` matrix. For example you can use [`LocalParameterization` in Ceres solver](http://ceres-solver.org/nnls_modeling.html#localparameterization). But it is pretty simple to implement this yourself in Python too. If the focal length is unknown, you'll have to add that as an optimization parameter as well.

Instead of nonlinear least squares there may be other methods. Some methods estimate the homography directly, but may not preserve the correct aspect ratio.

[image: warped using homography]

You can preview the homography by calling opencv's `WarpPerspective` function.

## Estimate translation and scale

This will involve knowing something about the geometry of the football field. You can detect some salient features unique to the football field and estimate the scale. For example you can detect the circular arcs using the circle Hough transform.

[image: football field superimposed]

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, this looks extremely promising! I have to say that I'm not well versed at all in the computer vision domain, so also a lot for me to investigate further. Maybe this is too much to ask, but do you have any code for the steps/results that you showed in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide the code because I am working on something similar at work. But for a general survey of sports field calibration, here is a collection of papers: https://github.com/cemunds/awesome-sports-camera-calibration Despite its simple appearance, it is a fairly difficult topic with active research going on.

Comment: @Daniel, Could you share the field image? Was it generated?